# sending char[][] and float[][] from C# to C++

Tags: c#, marshalling

How can i send float[6][6] which is in structure from C# program to C++ which also has the same structure to extract the data from c#
i had one more question similar to the above.i want to send char[][] from C# to C++.i have used string and at the receiving side i have used char[][] but C++ is taking some junk characters.I Would really appreciate for response.Thanks

Comment: Edit your question with the C++ signature of the structure, that will make it much easier to answer you properly.

Comment: Also, add the C# signature of the structure that you have now (including of course the various `MarshalAs` attributes). One thing the C++ side does not necessarily declare is what the char[][] should mean (ie. is it an array of zero terminated strings, or just a static array of chars?).

Answer (score 0):

If you control the code on both sides you could pass a `float[36]` which is much easier, and that would solve the first problem.

With regards to passing `char[]`, you should remember that in C(++) strings are `\0`-terminated, so you should add a `\0` at the end manually (in C# they have a `Length` property).

With regards to passing `char[][]`, I'm sorry but I don't know P/Invoke enough to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

By C++ you mean managed C++ or unmanaged C++? In second case you should write wrapper. Passing informations between C# and unamanaged C++ is impossible without wrapper.

Comment: Not true. Arrays of raw data, structs and "raw" strings can be easily passed back and forth between C++/C#.

Comment: What DarkWanderer said. You can usually do with "pure" C#, although using COM gets tricky. After all, that's exactly what the `MarshalAs` attribute is for - it includes such handy things as `SizeConst` which allow you to easily pass (or receive) fixed size arrays and strings. A C++ wrapper can be faster in some cases (only relevant in something you call very, very often), but even that can be written using unsafe C# (but as I said, using a C++ wrapper for COM may be prefferable to pure C#) - the C++ wrapper would need FullTrust anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure your C++ function is able to receive Unicode chars? If not consider sending `byte` instead of `char`
2. In C++ mulidimensional arrays are abstraction over regular arrays, for example char[4][5] is equals to char[20] and indexation supported by compiler. Consider sending float[36] array to C++.